# How to make div slide animation using onclick Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want the whole div to slide left after onclick, to be honest i have no clue what's wrong with my code :/
I'm also going to add when you click it again it goes back to regular position but i really need to figure out how i'm going to get the slide animation. It's the first time i'm using the animationName property. 
I want to do it in JavaScript and not JQuery.

```js
function function1(){
document.getElementById("front_page_blur").style.animationName = "slide";
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color:blue;
  }
.front_page_blur{
margin: auto;
width: 700px;
height: 425px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 9px black;
}
#front_page_blur{
transition: 1s ease;
animation: 2s;
}
.button {
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
margin-top: 35px;
text-align: center;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 10%;
display: inline-block;
}
#button1_text {
color: white;
font-family:Arial Black;
padding-top: 10px;
}
#button1{
background-color: rgba(0, 191, 255, 0.3);
z-index:2;
transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out;
}
#button1:hover {
background-color:rgba(0, 191, 255, 0.5);
transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes slide {
 from { left: 0px;}
 to { left: 200px;}
    
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="front_page_blur" id="front_page_blur">
<h1 class="welcomeMSG">Welcome To TheFunction</h1>
<h1 class="welcomeMSG" id="welcomeMSG_U">Choose Your Destination</h1>
<div class="button" id="button1" onclick="function1()">
<p id="button1_text">Animation</p>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: *I want to do it in JavaScript and not JQuery.* Your fiddle is using jQuery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m0qp457b/ try this then

Comment: @RachelGallen : I guess the OP is after CSS keyframe animation, atleast that's what his code suggests.

Comment: @harsha That's what i'm looking for, but how to get it in the JS code without affecting the original layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `left` is for absolute positioned elements. Try with `margin-left` instead:

```
@keyframes slide {
 from { margin-left: 0px;}
 to { margin-left: 200px;}   
}
```

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) for a quick tutorial on CSS animations. It could be useful on your task.

**UPDATE**

The following code have some changes, what i mentioned earlier, and also the way you call the CSS animation from javascript.

```js
function function1(){
  document.getElementById('front_page_blur').classList.add('slideAnim');    
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color:blue;
  }
.front_page_blur{
margin: auto;
width: 700px;
height: 425px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 9px black;
}
.slideAnim {
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
.button {
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
margin-top: 35px;
text-align: center;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 10%;
display: inline-block;
}
#button1_text {
color: white;
font-family:Arial Black;
padding-top: 10px;
}
#button1{
background-color: rgba(0, 191, 255, 0.3);
z-index:2;
transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out;
}
#button1:hover {
background-color:rgba(0, 191, 255, 0.5);
transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes slide {
 from {  margin-left: 0px;}
 to { margin-left: 200px;}
    
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="front_page_blur" id="front_page_blur">
<h1 class="welcomeMSG">Welcome To TheFunction</h1>
<h1 class="welcomeMSG" id="welcomeMSG_U">Choose Your Destination</h1>
<div class="button" id="button1" onclick="function1()">
<p id="button1_text">Animation</p>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

However, this kind of animation will only work the fist time. Then you need to find a way to restart it when you want it again (a trick could be remove the element from the page entirely and re-insert it).

Comment: THANK YOU! This was exactly what i was looking for! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @andyduly98 You are welcome. If this answer your question, you should accept this answer (mark it as the "accepted" answer).

Comment: can remove the class again after few second to be reuse in next click :   document.getElementById('front_page_blur').classList.remove('slideAnim');